# How do you find coefficient of specific x term in binomial expansion

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

How do you find the term in $x^5$ in the expansion of $((1/x)+x)^9$?

Comment: Hint: the terms are ${9 \choose j} (1/x)^j x^{9-j}$.  So which $j$ gives a term in $x^5$?

Comment: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the binomial theorem,
$$
(y+x)^9=\sum_{k=0}^{9}\binom{9}{k}y^kx^{9-k}
$$
For $y=x^{-1}$ this becomes
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{9}\binom{9}{k}x^{-k}x^{9-k}=
\sum_{k=0}^{9}\binom{9}{k}x^{9-2k}
$$
Can you finish?

> The only way to get $x^5$ is for $9-2k=5$, that is, $k=2$, so the coefficient is $\dbinom{9}{2}=36$.

Comment: I shall try. Let me compute this for a moment lol. Thanks for that.

Comment: Does -2j+9 = 5?

Comment: @AswinAbraham That's the key.

Comment: So I plug that back into the formula and get 36. Is that right?

Comment: @AswinAbraham I added the relevant spoiler. Good job.

Comment: Thank you so much. You have been a great help!